# Using Yii Querybuilder vs writing actual query

Tags: mysql, sql, yii

What are the pros and cons of using Yii QueryBuilder (or any other types of query builders) to construct actual queries instead of just writing out the queries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [guide](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.query-builder):
The Query Builder is best used when you need to assemble a SQL statement procedurally, or based on some conditional logic in your application. The main benefits of using the Query Builder include:

- It allows building complex SQL statements programmatically.
- It automatically quotes table names and column names to prevent conflict with SQL reserved words and special characters.
- It also quotes parameter values and uses parameter binding when possible, which helps reduce risk of SQL injection attacks.
- It offers certain degree of DB abstraction, which simplifies migration to different DB platforms.